# How to increment variable when the btnNext is clicked while using jcarousellite?

Tags: jquery, jcarousellite

I'm trying to get my variable to increment when the btnNext is clicked. Then when the counter reaches the length of my array I want to redirect to another page. So when the last image is shown and the btnNext fires again then it will redirect, but I can't get it working.

I've tried using a do/while loop..

```
$(function () {
        var myLiCount = $("li").length;
        var counter = 1;
        do {
            $(".nonCircular .carousel").jCarouselLite({
                btnNext: ".next",
                visible: 1,
                circular: false
            });
            counter = counter + 1;
        } while (counter != myLiCount);
        window.location.href('http://www.google.com');
    });
```

all that did was show the image for 2 seconds then redirected, so then I tried this...

```
$(function () {
        var myLiCount = $("li").length;
        var counter = 1;

            $(".nonCircular .carousel").jCarouselLite({
                btnNext: ".next",
                visible: 1,
                circular: false
            });
            counter = counter + 1;
        if(counter == myLiCount)
        window.location.href('http://www.google.com');
    });
```

but that didn't work either, it would get to the last image and do nothing after that.

I know for this to work I have to somehow increment on the btnNext click, but don't know how.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$(function () {
    $(".nonCircular .carousel").jCarouselLite({
        btnNext: ".next",
        visible: 1,
        circular: false
    });
    var counter = 1;
    $('.next').on('click', function () {
        counter = counter + 1;
        if (counter == $("li").length)
            window.location.href('http://www.google.com');
    });
});
```

Comment: I just tried as you suggested. It gets to the last image and when I click again it doesn't redirect. I see where you are going with this though, kinda.

Comment: In your console check `(counter == $(".jCarouselLite li").length` when you click last image. Just debug

Comment: I was just about to edit your answer, I left my var myCounter = $('li').Length and added that instead of .jCarouselLite li, to the if statement and its working. :)

Comment: @user2970223, Edited my answer It difficult debugging